# Ajax Json Results limited

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, rest

i am not getting all my results from a Query back.

```
var url = "https://url?top=10000";
$.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "GET",
        async: false,
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json"
        },
        }).success(function (data) {
             console.log(data);
        })
});
```

There result is limited to 1000 results...

```
meta:Object
    count: 10562
    next : 1000
```

Can anyone tell me how can i loop through the request to get all results?

When i put the request URL directly into my browser i get all results back.

Thanks for your help

Comment: you should remove the comma after the headers object

Comment: Thanks. But then i got the same result